# Unable to run grunt getting error default task not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to configure my project with grunt. when try to run a simple concat task I am getting below error.

[image]

here is my grunfile.js code.

```
module.export = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: '\n',
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['src/*.js'],
            dest: 'build/techsprint.js'
        }
    }

});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);

};
```

My grunt version is  grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v1.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a simple typo: `module.export` should be `module.exports`.